# 1 javascript for more elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a "division toggler" with jQuery, html and css. I am using the plugin embedit pro in my Wordpress site to save the html code so I can easily paste a shortcode in the Wordpress editor to display the HTML.

I made the HTML code 5 times, because I want to have 5 toggling divisions, now the problem is, when I click on one of the 5 buttons that should toggle the associated division, all the divisions will open instead of only one division that belongs to the button I just clicked on.

I know why this is, the divs have the same name. I can fix this to make every single toggler unique, but then I have to load the jquery 5 times, is there a way to load the jquery script once and make it possible to toggle a single div that belongs to the button?

My jQuery code:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/…; </script> 

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
    });
 }); 
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="flip">Klik hier voor meer informatie.</div> 
<div class="blueline"></div>
 <div class="panel">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Onderdelenhuishetanker.</div>
```

Greetings,

Thomas.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: You don't have to load jQuery 5 times, __ever__.

Comment: Try this url and if it's full fill your expectation than pls upload your code. http://jsfiddle.net/u3sns/5/

Comment: Provide some code to visualize

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand that. Can you make my code please? I would like to learn it, but at this moment i have to much to do. My code:        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script> And the html:        <div class="flip">Klik hier voor meer informatie.</div>
<div class="blueline"></div>
<div class="panel">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Onderdelenhuishetanker.</div>

Comment: If i could, i should do it. But at the moment, i have to much to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the panel class within the `flip` div, so that you can select it's child.

HTML:

```
<div class="flip">Klik hier voor meer informatie. 
  <div class="blueline"></div>
  <div class="panel">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Onderdelenhuishetanker.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".flip").click(function(){
  $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
  });
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xYM/)

Comment: No, the blue line has to be shown without toggling. But thanks for your answer, i hope there should be a way..

Comment: The blueline will be shown without toggling. http://jsfiddle.net/d5xYM/2/

It was just that I didn't have the CSS for the blue line which you do have, probably. I wrote a quick blueline css so that you know that it won't be toggled with the panel div.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. Daan you fixed it, special thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. You probably forgot to use selector $(this).

```
$("div.class").click(function () {

  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/qGeHe/

Comment: What do you mean? My knowledge about jquery is zero:D Should i show the code?

Comment: $(this) refers to the element that you are "working" on. In this code : div.class. It means: when you click on div.class (note : all the element div which got a class named "class"), toggle this element.

Comment: @enguerranws Yeah, that is correct. You want your onClick event to work for every div of that class. And I used $(this), to get clicked div inner element.

Answer (score 0):

You would never need 5 HTML or jQuery scripts integrated in your website.
Every HTML file is for a different page, you could copy the div's 5 times instead.

jQuery has selectors for selecting the right div's, `id` for single selection and `class` for multiple selection.

Once you've executed the `click()` function you don't want to select all the div's again, but only the one you've clicked. You can simply do that by using `$(this)`.

Your code would look like:

```
$("div.YOUR_CLASSNAME").click(function() {
   $(this).toggle();
});
```

change YOUR_CLASSNAME to the name of the class of the div.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't tell it right. I mean, when i click on a div, the other toggle's. i use one div like if its a "button", like this: http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/